# Boot rack capacity with mountain bike

Tags: mountain-bike, rack, transportation

I recently purchased a Spectral 29 AL6 which, with pedals, will be around the 16kg mark (or just under).

I currently drive a Holden Astra TS ([here's what it looks like](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/84/2004_Holden_Astra_%28TS_MY03%29_CDX_sedan_%282016-01-04%29_02_%28cropped%29.jpg/1599px-2004_Holden_Astra_%28TS_MY03%29_CDX_sedan_%282016-01-04%29_02_%28cropped%29.jpg)), which doesn't have a tow bar or roof rack currently.

I was hoping to be able to purchase and use a boot rack to get this bike around (rather than install roof racks or a tow bar), however most boot racks I can find have a max capacity PER BIKE of 15kg.
That said, if you purchase a 3 bike system, then the max capacity of the rack as a whole is 45kg.
If it helps, [here is one](https://www.99bikes.com.au/car-rack-allen-trunk-3-bike-deluxe) that I am looking at, and [here's another](https://www.99bikes.com.au/car-rack-buzzrack-mozzquito-trunk-mounted-bike-carrier).

Despite the fact the bike would be slightly over the PER BIKE capacity, it's well beneath the max capacity for the rack as a whole.

It makes sense to me that the boot rack, structurally, would be strong enough for the bike, but perhaps the mount/fixing where the bike goes is limited in strength. It then stands to reason (at least it makes sense to me) that you could reinforce the fixings to hold the bike down and you would be OK?

Any advice appreciated!

Comment: Maybe a silly question, but how would one even put a full suspension MTB on such a rack? With a nice horizontal top tube it looks easy enough, but a fully doesn’t have that.

Comment: My assumption was that I’d be able to fit it in on the top tube and have the bike angled. But this might be too tight. They do sell adapter’s that connect to the seat post.

Comment: With full suspension MTBs, the roof or hitch rack is well worth it, IMO

Comment: I had a similar problem, to carry my bike and my wife's e-bike (22kg without battery), and could only find one model: the Peruzzo Pure Instinct 2 — that seems to be distributed in Australia (there was also the Eckla Grizzly, but that has been discontinued).

Answer (score 4):

I doubt a kilogram will make any significant difference to the function of your rack.  However I'm not the manufacturer and they might refuse warranty if you "overload" the rack by their written specs.

You probably want to keep an eye on the welds and when you do your bike's periodic maintenance, also inspect the rack.  Or look it when loading your bike.

Also you might want to consider how to pad the rack better, to maintain your bike's paint and how to secure your bike so it doesn't fall off while travelling, and separately so it doesn't get stolen off your car.

Comment: Personally I tend to ride the bike :)

Comment: Haha - I was just relating this problem to my wife and she said the same thing; just ride the bike :D!
All the trails around me are about a 20 minute drive, so I'd rather save my energy for the mountain lol.
Thanks for your thoughts!

Comment: On both of those, all bikes share the same arm and therefore lever, so it's reasonable to think of the total load. After all, they should all be strapped rigidly to the arms. A 16kg bike close to the car will exert less torque on the fittings than 2 x 8 kg bikes because the centre of gravity will be closer to the pivot. BTW, some racks say 15kg per bike, 30kg total.  If driving to trails, be careful as access roads can often be rough - take it gently over potholes